# Dash in column name yields "object not found" Error

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, aesthetics

I have a function to generate scatter plots from data, where an argument is provided to select which column to use for coloring the points.  Here is a simplified version:

```
library(ggplot2)

plot_gene <- function (df, gene) {
   ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
     geom_point(aes_string(col = gene)) +
     scale_color_gradient()
}
```

where `df` is a **data.frame** with columns `x`, `y`, and then a bunch of gene names.  This works fine for most gene names; however, some have dashes and these fail:

```
print(plot_gene(df, "Gapdh")) # great!
print(plot_gene(df, "H2-Aa")) # Error: object "H2" not found
```

It appears the `gene` variable is getting parsed (`"H2-Aa"` becomes `H2 - Aa`).  How can I get around this? Is there a way to indicate that a string should not go through `eval` in `aes_string`?

### Reproducible Input

If you need some input to play with, this fails like my data:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,2), c(2,1), c(1,2), c(2,1))
colnames(df) <- c("x", "y", "Gapdh", "H2-Aa")
```

For my real data, I am using `read.table(..., header=TRUE)` and get column names with dashes because the raw data files have them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally R tries very hard to make sure you have column names in your data.frame that can be valid variable names. Using non-standard column names (those that are not valid variable names) will lead to problems when using functions that use non-standard evaluation type syntax. When focused to use such variable names you often have to wrap them in back ticks. In the normal case

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = H2-Aa)) +
  scale_color_gradient()
# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'H2' not found
```

would return an error but

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = `H2-Aa`)) +
  scale_color_gradient()
```

would work.

You can paste in backticks if you really want

```
geom_point(aes_string(col = paste0("`", gene, "`")))
```

or you could treat it as a symbol from the get-go and use `aes_q` instread

```
geom_point(aes_q(col = as.name(gene)))
```

The latest release of `ggplot` support escaping via `!!` rather than using `aes_string` or `aes_q` so you could do

```
geom_point(aes(col = !!rlang::sym(gene)))
```

Comment: Even command like `colnames(test) <- c("x", "y", "z", "H2 - O")` allows to set non-standard column names. good to know about `as.name`

Comment: Sure, you can set them to what ever you want, but when importing data like through `read.table`, then are properly renamed (unless you disable that). One should carefully consider whether non-standard column names are really worth all the extra trouble.

Comment: I literally used `read.table` with no other arguments than `header = TRUE`. It did not clean my column names as you suggest.

Comment: Wow. I find what very surprising. Are you sure you didn't set `check.names = FALSE` or rename them some other way? If I run `read.table(text="a-b,c\n1,2", header=T, sep=",")` I see that the `-` is turned into a `.`

Comment: Here's what I did to import my data: `nspCounts <- do.call(cbind, lapply(naiveSpleenFiles, function(x) { read.table(gzfile(x), header=TRUE) }))`  where `naiveSpleenFiles` is a vector of the zipped files to import.